# Как правильно написать условия для выборки из базы на php?

Tags: php

Есть 2 переменные, которые приходят через GET: приходят или одна, или другая. Соответственно, нужно подставить это пришедшее значение в переменную для выборки. Вот код примерный, но он не работает:

```
$stname = mysql_escape_string($_GET['stname']);
$serv = mysql_escape_string($_GET['serv']);
if (($serv == "") || ($serv == "all") && ($stname == "") || ($stname == "all")) {
  $znvc = '1';
} else { 
  $znvc = 'serv="'.$serv.'"' OR 'stname="'.$stname.'"';
}
  $query = 'SELECT id, data, time_n, time_k, time_kk, dmin, serv, stname, team1, team2 FROM igry WHERE '.$znvc.' ORDER BY data, time_n'; 


$res = mysql_query( $query );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stname = mysql_escape_string($_GET['stname']);
$serv = mysql_escape_string($_GET['serv']);

if ($serv && $serv != 'all') { 
    $znvc = 'WHERE serv="' . $serv . '"';
}

if ($stname && $stname != 'all') { 
    $znvc = 'WHERE stname="' . $stname . '"';
}

$query = 'SELECT id, data, time_n, time_k, time_kk, dmin, serv, stname, team1, team2 FROM igry ' . $znvc . ' ORDER BY data, time_n';
```

Comment: И лучше mysqli использовать :)

Comment: работает, но там еще 2 условия, кода эти переменные пустые или со значением "all" , то результат должен быть таким $znvc = '1';

Comment: перечитайте ответ. Пока вы не выложите больше кода, запрос, боюсь, вам никто не сможет помочь.

Comment: Думаю, ответ @ArchDemon ближе всего к итоговому. Автору же советую продумать логику в условии, возможно стоит проставить скобки.

Comment: добавил часть кода, там дальше запрос в базу куда и должна попадать переменная $znvc

Comment: Обновил ответ. Прям под ваш запрос

Comment: опять же все работает, но не выполняется еще одно условие, когда переменные пустые или со значением "all" то WHERE 1 должен быть, то есть показать все

Comment: если переменные пустые или *all*, то запрос в себе вообще не содержит конструкцию `WHERE`, что в свою очередь говорит о том, что выбираются ВСЕ, абсолютно ВСЕ данные из таблицы. Что непонятно?

Comment: спасибо, упустил этот момент